# Hölder-continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by $f(x) =\sqrt{|x|} $. Show that $$
\sup_{x, y\in [-1,1] x\neq y} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{1/2}}
$$
is finite.

I started by writing the definition but got stuck at first step only.

Comment: Presumably, where $x\neq y$.

Comment: Note that $|x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||$ so this becomes a statement about $x\neq y\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I changed $x \neq y$ but how did the second argument came. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y \ge 0$, $x \neq y$, then $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \le |\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}|$ and hence $$|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|^2 \le |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| |\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| = |x - y|^2.$$
This shows that $$\sup_{x\neq y \in[0,1]}\frac{|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|}{\sqrt{|x - y|}} \le 1.$$
If $x,y \le 0$ you can use the same argument, applied to $-x, -y$. If $x < 0 < y$ then $|x| > 0$ and hence $||x| - y| \le |x - y|$. In particular, since the square root is increasing on $[0,2]$, $$|\sqrt{|x|} - \sqrt{y}| \le \sqrt{||x| - y|} \le \sqrt{|x - y|}.$$

Comment: couldn't you just at beginning of  your argument  use $|x|$ and $|y|$ instead of $x$ and $y$  and  $||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$ in second line. To avoid different cases..

Comment: @nonlinearthought: yes, that works and gives a more elegant proof.